# irb command history keystroke in irb on eshell

Tags: emacs, irb, eshell

How can I access the command history when running irb in the emacs eshell?

When I run irb at the command line outside of emacs, I can use the up arrow to get the last command or ctrl-r to search the command history. In irb inside eshell, the up arrow does nothing (i.e. it runs `eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input` which does nothing in irb) and ctrl-r uses the emacs reverse search of the buffer instead of searching the command history. I guess irb never receives the up-arrow keystroke because it's bound to `eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input`, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Running `(global-unset-key (kbd "<up>"))` doesn't unbind the up-arrow in eshell and I'm not sure that's desirable anyway.

I know about inf-ruby, but I prefer using irb in eshell and besides `up-arrow` and `ctrl-r` don't work with that either.

It could be a problem with readline in irb, but I don't think so. `conf.use_readline` is nil on the commandline where irb command history works fine. Running irb --readline in eshell switches `conf.use_readline` to true but doesn't fix the up arrow or ctrl-r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs term mode (`M-x term`) in combination with `C-c C-j` / `C-c C-k` to temporarily allow yanking seems to be a good option. See another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979052/yanking-text-into-a-terminal-running-in-emacs).