# How to copy text to system clipboard in emacs while working in terminal buffer?

Tags: linux, macos, emacs, clipboard

I usually use emacs in a text terminal environment to manipulate text. In some particular situations, however, I want to interact with the system's clipboard, for example, copy text from emacs to a website. Is it possible to yank text to the system's clipboard directly from or to emacs? How?

Comment: In my experience, running Emacs in a terminal simply adds complications. Is running it graphically an option?

Answer (score 3):

Terminal in emacs is nothing but a buffer. If you are running terminal using `eshell`, you can directly copy to clipboard using <kbd>M-w</kbd> like you do in normal buffer.

If you are running terminal using `ansi-term`, yanking/copying is little tricky. You need to go to `term-line-mode` using <kbd>C-c C-j</kbd> copy whatever you want and come back to `term-char-mode` using <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd>. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979084/2698552) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

There's support for doing just that in Emacs-25 (see the NEWS file, looking for `xterm-extra-capabilities`), tho it depends on your terminal emulator providing corresponding support, which is apparently usually disabled by default, so you additionally need to configure your termninal emulator as well.

Another option is to install the `xclip` package, which is available on GNU ELPA.